# Create new array with data inside an array location

Tags: php, arrays

I'm in need to store information of the below kind inside an array. The problem I have is "new Array" inside an array wouldn't work obviously.

The below code is only to demonstrate what I want to achieve.

```
$propsArray= [
    array("A","NAME1", "ctype",new Array("ame","a4"), new Array("b2","b4","b7"), "locn1", "xval", "yval") ,
    array("A","NAME2", "ctype",new Array("x"), new Array("b1","b14"), "locn2", "xval", "yval") ,
    array("A","NAME3", "ctype",new Array("sdf"), new Array("b2"), "locn5", "xval", "yval") ,
    ];
```

Is there a way to achieve this using arrays? If yes, could you please show me using the data in this question? If it's not achievable using arrays, how could I achieve what I'm after?

Comment: Please post your code here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using three different methods for creating an array.

The first, available since PHP 5.4:

`$array = ['foo', 'bar'];`

The older way:

`$array = array('foo', 'bar');`

And something more suited to Javascript, **NOT** PHP:

`new Array("ame","a4");`

Forget the last one, and use one of the first two. Best to be consistent throughout. So either

```
$propsArray = array(
    array("A", "NAME1", "ctype", array("ame", "a4"), array("b2", "b4", "b7"), "locn1", "xval", "yval"),
    array("A", "NAME2", "ctype", array("x"), array("b1", "b14"), "locn2", "xval", "yval"),
    array("A", "NAME3", "ctype", array("sdf"), array("b2"), "locn5", "xval", "yval"),
);
```

or

```
$propsArray = [
    ["A", "NAME1", "ctype", ["ame", "a4"], ["b2", "b4", "b7"], "locn1", "xval", "yval"],
    ["A", "NAME2", "ctype", ["x"], ["b1", "b14"], "locn2", "xval", "yval"],
    ["A", "NAME3", "ctype", ["sdf"], ["b2"], "locn5", "xval", "yval"],
];
```

depending on your PHP version.

Comment: Hello rjdown - Thank you very much. To access the array values ["b2", "b4", "b7"], should I use `$propsArray[0][4][0]`,`$propsArray[0][4][1]`,`$propsArray[0][4][2]` respcetively?

Comment: Thank you very much. Highly appreciate your help. It's so easy to get lost between technologies.

Answer (score 0):

Use this. I think it will help you.

```
<?php
$cars = array
(
   array(array("ABC",123,456),22,18),
   array("BMW",15,13),
   array("Saab",5,2),
   array("Land Rover",17,15)
);

echo $cars[0][0][0]." ".$cars[0][0][1]." ".$cars[0][0][2].".<br>";
echo $cars[0][0].": In stock: ".$cars[0][1].", sold: ".$cars[0][2].".<br>";
echo $cars[1][0].": In stock: ".$cars[1][1].", sold: ".$cars[1][2].".<br>";
echo $cars[2][0].": In stock: ".$cars[2][1].", sold: ".$cars[2][2].".<br>";
echo $cars[3][0].": In stock: ".$cars[3][1].", sold: ".$cars[3][2].".<br>";
?>
```

Result:

```
ABC 123 456.
Array: In stock: 22, sold: 18.
BMW: In stock: 15, sold: 13.
Saab: In stock: 5, sold: 2.
Land Rover: In stock: 17, sold: 15.
```

Comment: You can use the any number of PHP understands multidimensional arrays that are two, three, four, five, or more levels deep. However, arrays more than three levels deep are hard to manage for most people.